# Cropping Images in half and saving both

Tags: crop

I have dozens of Images I need to part in the middle into 2 separate ones and save them afterwards. All of them are .tif
Since I am very new to python I can't get my head around on how to do this the smartest way and I've been struggling for days.
Anybody got a simple solution?

Thanks!